# CiviCRM What are all the possible variable fields available in greetings (Email and Postal)?

Tags: civicrm

When defining new email and postal greeting formats in Administer > Communications > Email Greeting Formats, I see a lot of available variables like `{contact.first_name}`, `{contact.last_name}`, and so on.

I would be happy to see the list of all available variables.

More precisely, when I refer to `{contact.individual_prefix}`, I have access to the field `Label` of the corresponding table, but I want to access the field `Description` of the same table. I would like to know if this is possible, and if I have to install some extension in order to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question also on https://civicrm.stackexchange.com

I received an answer there; see: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/39053/what-are-all-the-possible-variable-fields-available-in-greetings-email-and-post/39054#39054.